# How to implement ag-grid Infinite scrolling with pagination in reactJS

Tags: ag-grid, ag-grid-react

I am trying to learn reactjs and see if we can implement ag-grid infinite scrolling. My objective is to make server side call for every page change & show data to the user. I looked into the "https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-infinite-scrolling/#gsc.tab=0" but this is not clear to me on below points :

1)Where exactly the server call needs to be made so that i fetch only 10 rows from server for every page & display to the user.

Please help. Thanks a lot in advance.